# slideReveal script - How do you close all open "slides" before opening a new slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am playing around with this for a new site, and works great & easy to implement: http://nnattawat.github.io/slideReveal/

But one issue I can't determine, of you have multiple sliders, and one is already "out" from a previous event, how do you first make sure all other sliders are "closed" and THEN open the current slider?

I could do an if/then to check aach individual one, but I figure there must be a more elegant way...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of solving this problem is to create a "page-level controller". What this does is acts as a container and controller of sorts for events that happen in the page.

So you essentially have to "proxy" sliding open an closed a side (and adding a dependency of closing the other slide area), since the API doesn't seem to have any hooks or events that it emits like "onSlideOpen". That's what your controller will handle.

```
var PageController = function(){
  var $leftSlide = $('#leftSlider').slideReveal(), // You'll want to sub in
      $rightSlide = $('#rightSlider').slideReveal(); // your selector names


  return {
    openLeft: function() {
      $leftSlide.slideReveal('show');
      $rightSlide.slideReveal('hide');
    },
    openRight: function() {
      $rightSlide.slideReveal('show');
      $leftSlide.slideReveal('hide');
    }
  };
};

var pageController = new PageController();

pageController.openLeft(); // will slide reveal left side
pageController.openRight(); // will simultaneously open right and close left
```

Now you can even do things like check on the state of those slides in case you have other cross-dependencies.

A lot of people would probably handle this kind of thing by emitting events and catching them, but I really don't like the pub-sub model. It tends to get very brittle very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Use .slideReveal("hide") on all of the sliders, then use .slideReveal("show") on the one you want revealed.

One way to do this, would be to give all the sliders a class and use that as the selector

i.e.

```
$(".slider").slideReveal("hide");
$("#sliderYouWantToShow").slideReveal("show");
```